# Deriving the FLRW metric from the cosmological principle?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

I was reading some [notes](https://jila.colorado.edu/%7Eajsh/astr3740_14/flrw.pdf) (page 10/54 of pdf or page 214 of document) which state:

> A more formal approach to the derivation of the spatial FLRW metric
> from the cosmological principle starts with the proposition that the
> spatial components $G_{\alpha \beta}$ of the Einstein tensor at fixed
> scale factor a (all time derivatives of a set to zero) should be
> proportional to the metric tensor
>
> $$ G_{\alpha \beta} = - K g_{\alpha \beta}$$
>
> where ($\alpha$, $\beta$ = $1$, $2$, $3$).

It isn't obvious to me why the above equation implies isotropy or comes from the cosmological principle?

Comment: Or vice versa, for that matter.